# React-router-dom Render props isn't returning any component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom version 6.0.2 here and the "Render" props isn't working, every time I got to the url mentioned in the Path of my Route tag it keeps throwing me this error - "Matched leaf route at location "/addRecipe" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.". Can someone please help me with this issue

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home';
import AddRecipe from './components/AddRecipe';
import items from './data';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  const [itemsList, setItemsList] = useState(items)
  const addRecipe = (recipeToAdd) => {
    setItemsList(itemsList.concat([recipeToAdd]));
  }
  const removeItem = (itemToRemove) => {
    setItemsList(itemsList.filter(a => a!== itemToRemove))
  }
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/addRecipe" render={ ({history}) => {
          return (<AddRecipe onAddRecipe={(newRecipe) => {
            addRecipe(newRecipe);
            history.push('/');
          } }  />);
        } } />
        </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you properly exporting the component class/function in `AddRecipe.js`? Because my guess is that in your posted script, `AddRecipe` is null. The error message is simply fallout from that.

Answer (score 0):

In react-router-dom version 6, you should use element prop for this.

I suggest your read their [document on upgrading from version 5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) where they explain the changes.

For your problem, you should write something like this:

```
<Route 
   path="/addRecipe" 
   element={
      <AddRecipe 
         onAddRecipe={(newRecipe) => {
           addRecipe(newRecipe);
           history.push('/');
         } 
      />
   }  
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Route` component API changed significantly from version 5 to version 6, instead of `component` and `render` props there is a singular `element` prop that is passed a JSX literal instead of a reference to a React component (*via `component`*) or a function (*via `render`*).

There is also no longer route props (`history`, `location`, and `match`) and they are accessible only via the React hooks. On top of this RRDv6 also no longer surfaces the `history` object directly, instead abstracting it behind a `navigate` function, accessible via the `useNavigate` hook. If the `AddRecipe` component is a function component it should just access `navigate` directly from the hook. If it unable to do so then the solution is to create a wrapper component that can, and then render the `AddRecipe` component with the corrected `onAddRecipe` callback.

Example:

```
const AddRecipeWrapper = ({ addRecipe }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <AddRecipe
      onAddRecipe={(newRecipe) => {
        addRecipe(newRecipe);
        navigate('/');
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

...

```
const App = () => {
  const [itemsList, setItemsList] = useState(items);

  const addRecipe = (recipeToAdd) => {
    setItemsList(itemsList.concat([recipeToAdd]));
  };

  const removeItem = (itemToRemove) => {
    setItemsList(itemsList.filter(a => a !== itemToRemove))
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/addRecipe"
          element={<AddRecipeWrapper addRecipe={addRecipe} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
```