# Route render function not returning or rendering any element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So I am pretty new to React.js and not able to render an element from the Route module.
The console is returning that the leaf route at location does not have an element hence renders an empty page.
Other Route tags which use "element" function work correctly, so does this one.
This is a snippet from the App.js file

```
          <Route
        path="/"
        render={(props) => (
          <ContactList
            {...props}
            contacts={contacts}
            getContactId={removeContactHandler}
          />
        )}
      />
```

I have been following a youtube tutorial in hopes of learning React quickly. Now some of the functions used in this tutorial are deprecated currently. So is there a different function that I should be using instead of this? Appreciate any help

Edit:
The render and component function both are replaced by element prop, i found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70265517/16790124) helpful

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [react router docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)

Comment: Probably needs brackets not parens. `render={(props) => {`

Comment: and a return `render={(props) => { return <component> }}`

Comment: @Nikki9696 no that doesnt work either

Comment: Works in our code. What version of router you using?

Comment: @Nikki9696 6.2.1

Comment: Ah, we're on 5. 6 says to use element like this `<Route path="/" element={<App />}>`

Comment: They have a nice FAQ for how to do stuff like pass props here, since tutorials use 5 still all over. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

Comment: in the tutorial dude said that the render prop would help reduce render time since using the component prop(now using element instead as component is deprecated) would recreate the element every time which the render prop does not

Comment: @Nikki9696 thank you, seems render is also replaced by element now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone wants to know, from version 6 onwards `render` and `component` props is replaced by `element` prop that is passed as a literal instead of through an arrow function `()=>{}`.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70265134/react-router-dom-render-props-isnt-returning-any-component/70265517#70265517) explains it a bit more clearly.

Comment: apologies i meant element only. I had upvoted it, but for it be cast I need 15 reputation ;(   Thank you for your answer though, helped me a lot .

Answer (score 0):

The React router docs has recently been updated! Meaning syntax has changed. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804087/getting-blank-page-on-using-route-react?noredirect=1&lq=1) here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).